# Fatal error: Call to a member function sess_save() on null in path/to/system/libraries/Session/Session.php on line 309

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've searched for an answer to this for four days. Nothing. Could someone help me to understand why I'm getting that error. If you need further information about my set up I'd be glad to oblige.

Comment: It means the object of class is not being initialized and you can calling its function.

Comment: Have session library loaded whether in controller or autoload file?

Answer (score 0):

For using SESSION in codeigniter first of all you need to load the SESSION library in your controller and second you should set an encryption key for using it. to set the encryption key open your config.php file under application/config directory and find this one-

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'set your encryption key';
```